# Maven sources vs resources

Tags: java, maven

what is the difference between these two folders? Why my beans have to go in resources, so my web app to work?

```
src/main/java Application/Library sources
src/main/resources Application/Library resources
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `src/main/java` contains your java source codes. that is, your java packages, *.java files.

The `src/main/resources` contains "resources" file of your project. e.g. properties file, configuration files (xml, ini, conf....) they are in classpath of your project.

Usually the compiled *sources* (*.class files) and those *resources* would be in `target/classes`.

Your web app sources (e.g. Jsp/jspx, js, html...) should go to `src/main/webapp`

Comment: Where am I supposed to put package-documentation files? The application does not need them during runtime, but it's handy to put them inside the package that is documented. So I could (a) put them in `src/main/java/package/my-docs.md` or in (b) `src/main/resources/package/my-docs.md`. Or (c) keep them separate.